# Firebase throws Database exception when trying retrieve data into custom class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error when trying to retrieve data from firebase
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.ui.controls.CodeDescMast.

My POJO class class contains an int and string. I have defined the empty constructor, getter/setter methods and all these are public.

**CodeDescMast cdeDescMast = dSnpSht.getValue(CodeDescMast.class) is producing the database exception error.**

The question is I am using the same class for saving and retrieving , so why is this error cropping up.

**My POJO class**

```
public class CodeDescMast {
int code;
String desc;

public CodeDescMast() { }
public CodeDescMast(int code, String desc) {
    this.code = code;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

}

**Firebase helper class**

```
public class FbaseHelper {

DatabaseReference dbRef;
Boolean saved= null; 
CodeDescMast codeDescMast;
ArrayList<CodeDescMast> cdeDescAryList;

public FbaseHelper() { }
public FbaseHelper(DatabaseReference refDb) {
    this.dbRef = refDb;
    cdeDescAryList = new ArrayList<CodeDescMast>() ;
}

public void read(Context context) {

    String csvLine;

    InputStream is=null ;
    try {
        is = context.getAssets().open("b.csv") ;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)) ;
        codeDescMast = new CodeDescMast();
        while((csvLine = reader.readLine())!=null) {
           String[] row = csvLine.split(",") ;
           if (! row[1].equals("Desc")) {

               codeDescMast.setCode(Integer.valueOf(row[0]));
               codeDescMast.setDesc(row[1]);
               fBaseSave();

           }
        }

        is.close();

    } catch(IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();

    }
}
public Boolean fBaseSave() {
    try {
        dbRef.push().setValue(codeDescMast) ;
        saved = true;

    }catch (DatabaseException dbEx) {
        dbEx.printStackTrace();
        saved = false ;

    }

    return saved;
}
```

**Retrieve from Firebase**

```
  public ChildEventListener chldEvtListner = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnpSht : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long a = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            CodeDescMast cdeDescMast = dSnpSht.getValue(CodeDescMast.class) ;

            cdeDescAryList.add(cdeDescMast) ;
        }
    }
```

**JSON from Firebase**

```
{
  "-LAXQwrXU01IA5ha5eBW" : {
  "code" : 602,
  "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxx"
},
 "-LAXQwrezdMRpfVdEVY8" : {
 "code" : 603,
 "desc" : "xxxxxxx"
}
}
```

Comment: What is the reference that you are using to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

create a database reference

public FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

public DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("Node").child("Your ID or firebase uid reference");

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dSnpSht: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
     {
      CodeDescMast cdeDescMast = dSnpSht.getValue(CodeDescMast.class);             

      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

/// try this

Comment: I am just adding under the root which is in my mainactivity.java. I am able to view the values in dataSnaphot so the error occurs when I try getValue on the datasnapshot. Hence I would like to know why this error without changing anything.

Comment: in the current code that I have, the childadded is triggering properly, the parameter datasnapshot is also having proper values(at least the first row from firebase. In this situation why is the  datasnopt.getvalue  producing this error. I would like to understand why this error message is being thrown out before changing any code.

Comment: ValueEventListener will be triggered when  node changes, but ChildEventListener will also be triggered whenewer child values is changed as well

Comment: in your case i think valueEventListner is better because you are working on single layer architecture